# Windows 8 Remember ribbon settings

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, ribbon

Windows 8 explorer has ribbon interface and I'm frequently using it. The features I use most, located in View tab and Home tab. I never used Share tab.

But if I'm setting something in View tab, during the next launch, It's shows Home tab by default. Is there any way to tune explorer to remember that I used View tab last and show the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add items to the "Quick Access Toolbar (QAT)" to access them faster:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/improvements-in-windows-explorer)

> The new Quick Access Toolbar (QAT) in Explorer provides a lot of customization opportunities. Similar to Office, **by right-clicking any button in the ribbon, you can add it to the QAT.** Additionally, you can choose to have the QAT display above or below the ribbon, and to display the ribbon in an open or minimized state. This is a big increase in the level of customization available in Explorer (you can choose approximately 200 commands to add to the QAT) and returns it to a level equal to or greater than we had in Windows XP.

Comment: Perfect! However, I would like to keep it above ribbon. But if I keep it above ribbon, it's unable to re-size the width.